# Angular 6 how to check if my pipe filter returns an empty array

Tags: angular, pipe, ngfor

i have a list of dinosaures that i iterate throught it and then i added a search input to filter the list by login property like this

```
<input type="text" class="recherche" [(ngModel)]="loginToSearch" placeholder="Entrez votre recherche ici...">

    <li *ngFor="let dinosaure of dinosauresList | filter: login : loginToSearch" class="list-group-item text-left">
      <div>
        <img class="img-thumbnail" src="{{ dinosaure.profileImage}}">
        <label class="name">
          {{dinosaure.login}}<br>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-plus">
        <label class="pull-right">
          <a class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-plus" 
                 (click)="onClickAddFriend(dinosaure)"
            title="View"></a>
        </label>
      </div>

    </li>
```

but i want to add a condition to display a message or form when there are no results returned by the filter , i tried many solutions that i found but none of them worked for me.

this is my filter :

```
   @Pipe({
     name: 'filter'
  })
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

      transform(value: any, args: any, loginToSearch: string): any {
        if (!value) {

         return null;
         }
      if (!args && !loginToSearch) {
              return value;
             }
         loginToSearch = loginToSearch.toString().toLowerCase();
             return value.filter(data => {
           return data.login.includes(loginToSearch);
                 });

                }

             }
```

Comment: why don't you just wrap your  <li> </li> in an *ngIf ?

Comment: @BELLIL i didn't find the right condition to put in the *ngIf that's why

Comment: For performances reasons you should use a filter or sort pipe. The official angular documentation recommends avoiding it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you to change the manner of work,

you can add an ng on `(ngModelChange)` to your front

so your input will be like this

```
<input type="text" class="recherche" [(ngModel)]="loginToSearch" placeholder="Entrez votre recherche ici..."  (ngModelChange)="onFilterValueChange()" >
```

and then in your component you declare a temporary list and you search your value

```
temporaryList = [];
onFilterValueChange(){
        if(this.loginToSearch){
         this.temporaryList = this.dinosauresList.filter(data => data.login.includes(this.loginToSearch));} 
         else {  this.temporaryList  = this.dinosauresList;
        }}
```

and then in your html you can do

```
<div *ngIf="temporaryList  === 0;else results"> Your error message  </div>

<ng-template #results>
    <li *ngFor="let dinosaure of temporaryList " class="list-group-item text-left">
      <div>
        <img class="img-thumbnail" src="{{ dinosaure.profileImage}}">
        <label class="name">
          {{dinosaure.login}}<br>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-plus">
        <label class="pull-right">
          <a class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-plus" 
                 (click)="onClickAddFriend(dinosaure)"
            title="View"></a>
        </label>
      </div>

    </li>

</ng-template>
```

If you insist to work with your pipe, you'll have to create a `service` that contains an `event emitter` that inform your component when your list is empty, if you create a stackblitz i will be able to give you more help

Comment: i have thought the same as you !

Comment: but i think there still problem when i delete from input it does not restore the array

Comment: and also i tried looking for one element and i found it but when i delete and look for another existing element it won't work it shows error message since the input is empty

Comment: sorry but i never used stackblitz but i could give you a github repository if you want just the front end part

Comment: can you take a look at my modified code ? i added a condtion in onFilterValueChange(), you should reinitialize if loginToSearch is empty

Comment: yes yes it works fine , there is just one tiny problem when i delete from the input it doesn't trigger the (change)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208597/discussion-between-bellil-and-aouadi-slim).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using two ng-containers

The answer:

```
<input type="text" class="recherche" [(ngModel)]="loginToSearch" placeholder="Entrez votre recherche ici...">

<ng-container *ngIf="dinosauresList | filter: login : loginToSearch;let filteredDinosauresList">
  <ng-container *ngIf="filteredDinosauresList.length>0;else noResultsView">
    <li *ngFor="let dinosaure of filteredDinosauresList" class="list-group-item text-left">
      <div>
        <img class="img-thumbnail" src="{{ dinosaure.profileImage}}">
        <label class="name">
          {{dinosaure.login}}<br>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-plus">
        <label class="pull-right">
          <a class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-plus"
             (click)="onClickAddFriend(dinosaure)"
             title="View"></a>
        </label>
      </div>

    </li>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>

<div #noResultsView>Your error message for no results</div>
```

- Inside the first `ng-container`, we filter and assign the filtered list into a local template variable using `let`.
- Then in the second `ng-container` we check the length of that filtered list to show the empty results view or not.
- We can use the same local template variable inside the `*ngFor` in order to prevent multiple filter operations